# Jquery variable showing [object Object] in html but shows correct value in console.log

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update a class name based on a click event, I have stored the value in a variable which prints the correct value in console log but in the html it shows [object Object].

Here is my html and jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  addclass = function() {
    var mydata = jQuery('.testimonial-section .slick-track > .ult-item-wrap.slick-current.slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
    console.log(mydata);
  }
  jQuery(".slick-dots li").click(function(mydata) {
    addclass();
    jQuery('.slick-track').addClass('index-' + mydata);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="slick-track">
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="0">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="1">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="3">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="slick-dots">
    <li class=""><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
    <li class="slick-active"><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
    <li class=""><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here any suggestion will be really helpful. Also is there a way to run the "addclass" function if the carousel automatically shifts the "slick-active" class to the next div?

Comment: Where are you adding this to the `html`?

Comment: Where is `testimonial-section` in your HTML? Where does this code add anything to html?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here. `mydata` is the `event` object being passed in to the `click` handler on the `li`, hence why you get `[object Object]` when you coerce it to a string. If you're expecting the `mydata` variable you define in the `addclass` function to have scope within  the event handler, it won't. There's also much better ways to do whatever you need to do, if you could tell us exactly what that is.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry for not being clear with my question, what I'm looking to do is when I click on `slick-dots li` it should grab the attribute of `data-slick-index` and add a class to `slick-track like` `index-0`.

Comment: @Barmar I missed the `testimonial-section` class it should be at in the first `div`.

Answer (score 0):

`mydata` in `addclass()` is not the same as `mydata` in the `click` handler function. Each function has its own scope for local variables.

In the click handler, `mydata` contains the `Event` object that jQuery passes to handler functions. Calling `addclass()` has no effect on this.

`addclass` should return the value that it retrieves, then you can assign this to a variable in the handler.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  addclass = function() {
    var mydata = jQuery('.testimonial-section .slick-track > .ult-item-wrap.slick-current.slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
    console.log(mydata);
    return mydata;
  }
  jQuery(".slick-dots li").click(function() {
    var mydata = addclass();
    jQuery('.slick-track').addClass('index-' + mydata);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="slick-track">
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="0">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="1">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ult-item-wrap slick-slide" data-animation="animated no-animation" data-slick-index="3">
        <div class="aio-icon-component">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="slick-dots">
    <li class=""><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
    <li class="slick-active"><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
    <li class=""><i type="button" style="color:#333333;" class="ultsl-record" data-role="none"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```